# How to transform a list into a Dataframe Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a list with two columns I would like to use as rows and columns index of a matrix and one which would be the data. How may I construct a matrix like we do with csv files ?

[image]

Here is the list I have. I would like to have `count` as data, `eclipse_id` as the index and the last one as the columns index :

```
In[31]: listado

Out[31]:[{'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 10616, 'subscriber_id': 13},
 {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 10337, 'subscriber_id': 13},
 {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 9562, 'subscriber_id': 13},
 {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 10660, 'subscriber_id': 13},
 {'count': 1L, 'eclipse_id': 10621, 'subscriber_id': 13},
```

And my attempt :

```
pd.DataFrame(data=listado[1:,0],
            index=listado[2:,0]
            columns=listado[3:,0])

With the error message :

  File "<ipython-input-33-f87ac772eb69>", line 3
    columns=listado[3:,0])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The output should be like :

```
subscriber_id  13   14    15     16
eclipse_id       
9562            1    1     0    ...
10337           1    0     0    ...
10616           1    2     0    ...
10621           1    1     1
10660           1    0     0
```

Comment: Missing comma in your ctor params `pd.DataFrame(data=listado[1:,0],
            index=listado[2:,0], #<- here
            columns=listado[3:,0])` also even if you added the comma, you can't slice a list by passing a tuple which is what will happen using `[1:,0]`

Comment: Additionally can you post what the desired output is as your syntax is incorrect it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
listado = [
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10616, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10337, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 9562, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10660, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10621, 'subscriber_id': 13}]

df = pd.DataFrame(listado)
print (df)
   count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
0      1       10616             13
1      1       10337             13
2      1        9562             13
3      1       10660             13
4      1       10621             13

df = df.pivot(index='eclipse_id', columns='subscriber_id', values='count')
print (df)
subscriber_id  13
eclipse_id       
9562            1
10337           1
10616           1
10621           1
10660           1
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(['eclipse_id','subscriber_id'])['count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
subscriber_id  13
eclipse_id       
9562            1
10337           1
10616           1
10621           1
10660           1
```

---

If duplicates need aggregate data by `mean`, `sum`...:

```
listado = [
{'count': 5, 'eclipse_id': 9562, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 4, 'eclipse_id': 9562, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 9562, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10660, 'subscriber_id': 13},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 10621, 'subscriber_id': 13}]

df = pd.DataFrame(listado)
print (df)
   count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
0      5        9562             13 < same 9562, 13, different 5
1      4        9562             13 < same 9562, 13, different 4
2      1        9562             13 < same 9562, 13, different 1
3      1       10660             13
4      1       10621             13

df = df.groupby(['eclipse_id','subscriber_id'])['count'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
subscriber_id        13
eclipse_id             
9562           3.333333 <- (5+4+1)/3 = 3.333
10621          1.000000
10660          1.000000
```

Or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='eclipse_id', 
                    columns='subscriber_id', 
                    values='count', 
                    aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
subscriber_id        13
eclipse_id             
9562           3.333333 <- (5+4+1)/3 = 3.333
10621          1.000000
10660          1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help jezrael ! Yet I don't know why but my df output doesn't look like yours when I do `df = pd.DataFrame(listado)` like it is shown in the [following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xON3o.png). The error is : `KeyError: 'subscriber_id'`

Comment: It gives me  : `[nan, 6413.0, 6521.0, 6525.0, 6527.0, 6528.0, 6530.0...`. I have no problem computing `df = df.pivot(index='subscriber_id', columns='eclipse_id', values='count')` but I have the issue above when printing `df` out.

Comment: Question is, what do you need? because select `subscriber_id` is not possible, because it is only columns.name. Check it by `print (df.columns.name)`

Comment: Next if use `df = pd.DataFrame(listado)` and then `print (df.dtypes)` then it return `eclipse_id` is `float`. Problem is some value(s) is missing, so get `NaN`s and all values are converted to `floats`. Solution is first replace `NaN`s by some scalar like `0` and then convert to  int-  `df['eclipse_id'] = df['eclipse_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)`. And then use `pivot`. ;)

Comment: I don't know what happened. I just computed it again and ... it worked. Yet do you know how to fill `NaN` with zeroes and have the column as pure integer ?  Why does the first column index is `NaN` ? Here is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3N3A.png)

Comment: Check commnet before, If use `df['eclipse_id'] = df['eclipse_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)` get it ;)

Comment: oops, sorry. Need  `df['subscriber_id'] = df['subscriber_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)`. Or if need repalce all values to int `df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Very last question : how may I switch the columns and the rows ?

Comment: Sure, only swap column nmaes in pivot.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='subscriber_id', columns='eclipse_id', values='count')`